# Populate database using spring / hibernate / flyway / postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to populate my database with around 150 different values (one for each row).
So far, I've found two different ways to implement the inserts, but none of them seems to be the best way to do it.

- **Flyway + Postgres:** One of them is to create a migration file and make use of the `COPY` command from postgres but to do so, I need to give superuser permissions to the user and that doesn't seem to be a good choice.
- **Spring boot:** place a `data.sql` file in the classpath with a lot of inserts. If I'm not wrong I would have to write 150 `insert into...` statements.

In previous projects, I have used liquibase and it has a `loadData` command which is very convenient to do what is says it does. You just give the file, table name and that's it. You end up with your csv file values in your table rows.

Is there an alike way to do that in flyway? What is the best way to populate the database?

Comment: 150 inserts shouldn't take all that long, but it sounds like perhaps you could just do one insert with a values clause that contains 150 rows.

Comment: Yes.. for the moment I'm just running a migration with 150 insert statements. I'm just wondering what would be the best way to handle it if I have thousands or millions of values.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way, you can find more info on the official documentation's [page](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#versioned-migrations)

You need to add some spring boot properties too:

```
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration
spring.flyway.schemas=public
```

Properties details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-migration-properties)

In my case, a use **R**epetables scripts by my needs but take care with the prefixes
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flyway is a direct competitor of liquidbase, so if you need to track the status of migrations, manage distributed migration (many instances of the same service start simultaneously, and only one instance should actually execute a migration), check upon startup which migration should be applied and execute only relevant migrations, and all other benefits that you have previously expected from "migration management system", then you should use Flyway rather than managing SQLs directly.

Spring boot has integrations with both Flyway and Liquidbase, so you can place your migrations in the "resources" folder, define a couple of properties and spring boot will run Flyway automatically.

For example, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway) you can find a tutorial of Flyway integration with spring boot.

Since flyway's migrations are SQL files- you can place there whatever you want (even plSQL I believe), it will even manage transaction per migration guaranteeing that the migration "atomicity" (all or nothing, no partial migration).

So the straightforward approach would be creating a SQL file file with 150 inserts and running it via flyway in spring or even via maven depending on your actual setup.

If you want more fine-grained control and the SQL is not flexible enough, its possible to implement Migration in Java Code. See [Official Flyway Documentation](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/java#creating-a-java-based-migrations)